# Typescript Union issues

Tags: typescript

Typescript error:

```
Property 'sub' does not exist on type 'AppSyncIdentityCognito | AppSyncIdentityIAM | AppSyncIdentityOIDC | AppSyncIdentityLambda'.
  Property 'sub' does not exist on type 'AppSyncIdentityIAM'.
```

Typescript does not catch that the property `sub` exists on both `AppSyncIdentityOIDC` and `AppSyncIdentityCognito`. What is going on here?

---

```
export type Context = {
  arguments: any;
  args: any;
  identity: Identity;
  source: any;
  error?: {
    message: string;
    type: string;
  };
  stash: any;
  result: any;
  prev: any;
};

type AppSyncIdentityIAM = {
  accountId: string;
  cognitoIdentityPoolId: string;
  cognitoIdentityId: string;
  sourceIp: string[];
  username: string;
  userArn: string;
  cognitoIdentityAuthType: string;
  cognitoIdentityAuthProvider: string;
};

export type AppSyncIdentityCognito = {
  sourceIp: string[];
  username: string;
  groups: string[] | null;
  sub: string;
  issuer: string;
  claims: any;
  defaultAuthStrategy: string;
};

type AppSyncIdentityOIDC = {
  sub: string;
  issuer: string;
  claims: any;
};

type AppSyncIdentityLambda = {
  resolverContext: any;
};

type Identity =
  | AppSyncIdentityCognito
  | AppSyncIdentityIAM
  | AppSyncIdentityOIDC
  | AppSyncIdentityLambda
  | null
  | undefined;


export function request(ctx: Context) {
  if (!ctx.identity) {
    return;
  }
  if (!ctx.identity.sub) { // <-- here is the typescript error
    return "Unauthorized";
  }

  return "We got a sub";
}

export function response(ctx: Context) {
  return ctx.result;
}
```

See [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&useDefineForClassFields=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noLib=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=false&noImplicitOverride=false&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=false&disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect=false&ts=4.9.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NTwLxwDeAUHHAIZQDmArgLbDYDOAXBZogNykXWvtceASwAmjGEKRsAkmOyTBZJhBpQAxsDbkO3MsChRoAfjYkyZBkybkqmuExhQhmKrvNIUbB05duAvm4O5EwAFlo6PFDATDQANjDhinBgUQBuidwBxMQeqACCYGAAyoiYarLiCtJ5ALJwBGYUamoq2LJejs6uPC1UmJIQFfJIAAoQELHt9p2+PRB9A0MSSFPeXYEq6sDSYB0+VADaALpuNEz6mOQMe+s8Z-p5UJg3s2S9-TCDcsuIeTQwIQAKsg7GtXnB3otvgo-gCRoZUqJ9C9ulliKBILAECC4AViqVytCkBgFp96kQeMpVBodijjqdzk8rqCZt0yFRDDQwPwwYcjnAAD5wTBxWKBGgAIxRbiEVhoyOm+zcali5CEdH42iSYgAZuQ4jBYSEio5yDgqIhpcQ0blcYUSmUlgoAPLSAAiaHJjRiUsVtzIspiCt5ytV6s1ERtOLxDsJlSQABkrhKROQvZFohNUvoMNhcBlrdwcjinUh6jwhTGCaXECSPhAK3b8Y6iYhqjVG1WW-HEK6PZ37dXW0m6CnyI2RbFYo2aJhdc5gCIi+jwNB4DrZ2oJFg4FEAI7yhwACi3IDYuZwIBgAEoKQGdXAjwBCU8AOiRw0Qt8aZCiMFUmD+MID7Pm+H4-K+PrfnAAD0MFwAAPAAtEhcAhPoqCygg6HYigTBqE4YDwPohhQDwv7AP+TxwAARAAqpc-whNAQgAF6LjRQEZlRmC0QA6qgVAQPAaY+px1rZBia5wBuZTbrxURMJAmDnCeMBnugWCXjed67pRAEQupr6KQamTEEAA) for the full code.

Comment: What if it is `AppSyncIdentityIAM`? Then there is no `sub` property so accessing `sub` is unsound (unsafe).

Comment: `any` effectively disables typescript. start removing those `any` types sooner than later. it's only going to get harder the longer you allow them to remain in your programs and write code around them. design your types _first_ then write code to support them.

Comment: All types are extracted from [@aws-appsync/utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-appsync/utils) copied them over to Typescript Playground to be test around a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that `ctx.identity` does not contain a `sub` property :

```
if (!('sub' in ctx.identity)) {
  return "Unauthorized";
}
```